# Problema de precisão no Geolocation maps V3

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou criando um app web de localização, utilizando `geolocation` da `google maps v3`.

O problema é que quando minhas funções trabalham, elas não conseguem obter minha localização `CORRETA NO Chrome do COMPUTADOR`, mas quando utilizo o navegador(Chrome ) do `MEU CELULAR ELE OBTÉM`.

```
// Read location from browser
function readLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
    }
}

// Get the latitude and the longtitude
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}
```

> Pensei que o problema estava no meu código, mas não está, pois ao utilizar o próprio app de localização da google, obtive a mesma imprecisão de localização.

[LINK PARA APP DA GOOGLE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

**Qual seria a teoria correta para justificar o porque que no meu computador é achada uma localização e no meu celular é outra diferente?**

Comment: Na teoria: seu celular fornece a localização com ajuda do GPS e via navegador, ele infere pelo IP.

Comment: Como resolver? Até um tempo não tinha esse problema com a google. Você testou clicando no link?

Comment: +1 para incentivar a evitar duplicar perguntas e se manter na que você criou originalmente, recomendo que leia isto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3966/3635

Answer (score 1):

Não existe precisão mesmo, o googlemaps é uma ferramenta que trabalha sempre sendo melhorada e dados atualizados, mas entenda que isto é a nível global e mesmo sendo uma das maiores empresas do mundo com satélite e tudo mais ainda sim é necessário que alguém atualize estes dados.

Lugares que costumam ter mais precisão são os mais populosos e mesmo assim não tem como atualizar todos, o GPS como você mesmo diz aumenta a precisão justamente por que funciona de maneira diferente, ele funciona dispositivo GPS com o sinal de GPS "diretamente", já nos computadores Desktop com aplicações Web o processo é todo online e envia os dados que é possível localizar, mas ainda sim funciona com uma "base dados" e dificilmente vai ser tão preciso.

Na minha cidade (corrigiram no final de 2015) havia um erro de numeração de casas no GoogleMaps de aproximadamente 4km, a numeração na metade da avenida principal era numero 6000 (cidade pequena) e ia até 8000, mas dentro destes quatro quilômetros o 6000 inicia duas vezes, algumas pessoas na empresa usavam o streetview para se guiar, mas acabavam se perdendo, isto acontece porque quem atualiza é o Google e então não tem o que fazer muito do lado da sua aplicação.

No entanto algumas leituras podem lhe interessar:

- [How accurate is the Lat/Lng that you get from SV API's getPosition()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15642304/1518921)
- [How accurate is the google maps latitude and longitude I am using?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/69031)

Comment: Então eu devo abandonar a minha ideia de aplicações Web em computadores Desktop para se obter a geolocalização?

Comment: @Lollipop não de maneira alguma eu quis dizer isso, quero dizer que infelizmente estamos limitados e isso talvez você deva repassar em forma de mensagem ao usuário final, avisando que Desktop não tem como ter precisão. Pensa assim comigo, o usuário alimenta os dados do aplicativo? Se sim, você pode dar a opção do usuário ajustar a localização, é uma ideia que pode ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Simples, os celulares atuais são providos de dispositivos de GPS(Global Position System) quais possibilitam aos softwares obter uma posição precisa do indivíduo.

Em um computador onde na maioria dos casos o dispositivo de GPS se faz ausente a localização é feita através do endereço IP do usuário e considerando que através do [IP](http://www.feedbackmag.com.br/rastreamento-por-ip-como-funciona/) onde você só consegue descobrir a região do indivíduo de forma imprecisa.